# windows Service in Golang takes much time than normal exe

Tags: go, windows-services

I have a below code which performs multiplication .I have calculated the time it takes to do the same and logged it into a file .Time is always 3.0002ms on average .

```
func Mul() {

t := time.Now()
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {

    c := i * 2
    fmt.Println(c)

}

l, err := logutil.GetLogger("replicateIT.main")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error in getting current method" + err.Error())

}

sub := time.Since(t)
fmt.Println("The time difference", sub.String())
l.Log(logutil.INFO, "time difference "+sub.String())
```

}

Then I have included the function call  in execute method of svc package to run this as service ,as given below .The time difference now is 294.0168ms .

Why is it taking time this much ? Am i doing anything wrong in implementing service ?

Please give some suggestions !

```
  func (m *myservice) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest,   changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StartPending}
fasttick := time.Tick(500 * time.Minute)
slowtick := time.Tick(10 * time.Minute)
tick := fasttick

go Mul()

//creates log instance
l, err := logutil.GetLogger("replicateIT.main")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error in getting current method" + err.Error())

}
l.Log(logutil.INFO, "-----------------STARTED OUR APP------------------------")

changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
 loop:
   for {

    select {
    case <-tick:
    case c := <-r:
        switch c.Cmd {
        case svc.Interrogate:
            changes <- c.CurrentStatus
            // Testing deadlock from https://code.google.com/p/winsvc/issues/detail?id=4
            //time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            //changes <- c.CurrentStatus
        case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:
            break loop
        case svc.Pause:
            changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Paused, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
            tick = slowtick
        case svc.Continue:
            changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
            tick = fasttick
        default:
            elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("unexpected control request #%d", c))
        }
    }
}

changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running}

return
 }
```

Benchmark has been added for Mul Function and the startService function which invokes Mul .

```
package testing

// from fib_test.go 
 import (
 "strconv"

 "fmt"
 "service"
 "testing"
 "example")

 func BenchmarkMul10(b *testing.B) {
  // run the Fib function b.N times
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
      example.Mul()
     }
}
 var i int

func BenchmarkStartSer(b *testing.B) {
   fmt.Println("START SERVICE")
    // run the Fib function b.N times

   for n := 0; n <b.N; n++ {
        i++
     err:=service.InstallService("PTS-EBDR-MULT"+strconv.Itoa(i),"PTS-EBDR-MULT"+strconv.Itoa(i))
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        break

    }

}
```

}

Comment: So, what happens if you use the benchmarking code from the `testing` standard package in your `Mul()` function and run your code there under benchmarking say 1000 times in a row (to get consistent weighted median result)?

Comment: I mean, your approach to measuring is so low-tech you appear to rather measure the fluctuations of the world's Ether rather than your code.

Comment: You could start [here](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go). Keep in mind, that to make `testing` package work in "normal" code (that is, code which is run by means other than executing `go test`) you need to explicitly call out to that package: see the documentation on the `testing.M` type and its methods and accompanying functions.

Comment: I will use the testing package to  benchmark the above function.Once it is done ,I will update the results.Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: As you said ,I tried benchmarking as given below for Mul function as a normal function and as service .